# How to skip BKPT instruction in GDB on ARM?

Tags: c, arm, gdb, embedded, stm32

i use `__asm__ __volatile__ ("bkpt #0");` in code. GDB stop with signal SIGTRAP. Ok, but i want the code to run further.

in GDB i use 'continue', 'skip', but i still stay on the same instruction.
How to skip programm bkpt in GDB?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded/+bug/1383840

Answer (score 1):

You need to do step in GDB.

If you use Eclipse use F6 (step over).

Works both with openOCD, seggerGDBserver and stm32 gdb server.

Breakpoint instruction:
[image]

---

Step over, but step in works as well

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Does not work. Does it have anything to do with semihosting?