# How to step past an Arm BKPT in gdb?

Tags: assembly, arm, gdb, embedded

In Arm assembly, I set a breakpoint via `bkpt` instruction.  Gdb stops correctly on this, but hitting `s` just freezes.  How can I continue to step the program?

This question [How to skip BKPT instruction in GDB on ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117662/how-to-skip-bkpt-instruction-in-gdb-on-arm) is similar, but the answer given a) is for GUIs only and b) according to the comments, doesn't work!

I think the root cause is that `bkpt` does *not* advance the `pc` register, causing an endless loop.  Perhaps it's possible via a custom function that advances the `pc` one time, or some type of trigger to do so anytime it hits a `bkpt`.

(My target is a Cortex M4).

---

## Update

I'm using gdb remote to debug a Cortex M MCU.  Hitting Ctrl-C gives the following (perhaps by design?):

```
warning: Error detected on fd 11
Remote communication error.  Target disconnected.: Resource temporarily unavailable.
(gdb) c
The program is not being run.
(gdb)
```

Comment: How about `jump $pc+4`?

Comment: @Jester It's actually `set $pc = $pc+2$`.  This works.  But if you forget it, even once, and hit `s`, there's no way out.  This calls for automation.

Comment: Control-C doesn't work to interrupt and get GDB back to its command prompt?  I'd hope that would work on a native ARM Linux setup where the OS can always interrupt a user-space process, but attaching to a simulator or real hardware as a GDB-remote possibly not, perhaps because GDB's UI is insufficient; I'd hope that a debugger could in general break into execution on the remote no matter what it was doing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, Ctrl-C disconnects entirely - see update.

Comment: Did you follow the link in that other question? It might shed some light on this behavior, it looks like it is intentional.