# Breakpoint instruction in stm32 will execute infinite with next

Tags: embedded, stm32

I am currently learning with an STM32 microcontroller, and the CPU I’m using is an ARM Cortex-M4. In my code, I’ve added a breakpoint instruction. However, when I use the GDB next command, the program gets stuck.

[image]

Comment: Try the "Continue" command, it may jump to the next breakpoint

Comment: @Geisterfahrer "Continue" command will still stay in the same breakpoint

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip BKPT instruction in GDB on ARM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75117662/how-to-skip-bkpt-instruction-in-gdb-on-arm)

Answer (score 2):

Theere is no exit from `bkpt` instruction except setting the new `pc` register value - pc+=2 or pc+=4;

IDEs have this implemented in the step button. If you want to use command line `gdb` you need to do it manually.

Comment: In my setup (gdb+openOCD+STLink-v2), on 'F407 I can single-step ('s') and run ('c') this sequence of bkpts just fine; next ('n') freezes as OP said. I'd say, the real answer is "it depends". I don't intend to dig deep into this, but gdb itself is "twice removed" from the hardware, through its server (in my case openOCD, in case of CubeIDE it's ST's gdb server AFAIK) and through the debugging hardware (in my case STLink-v2). IMO either of them can recognize a potential "deadlock" and "act against", not just the "user-end-debugger" (IDE) itself.

Comment: "There is no exit from bkpt instruction except setting the new pc register value - pc+=2 or pc+=4;" - can you provide a source for this information? I read through ARMv7-M architecture manual, but it doesn't contain much information about that instruction (which is surprising given how it is usually a valuable source of info)

Comment: @Ilya read how to exit the degug state